# riot observable does not work in recursive function

Tags: riot.js

riot observable does not work in recursive function?

event can not be fired continuously

plunker: ijOIsQMSt37wqAvIFGx6

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <script>
      var o = riot.observable();
          o.on('foo', function(done){
          console.log('receive.');
          done();
      })
      function recur(){
        o.trigger('foo', recur)
      }
      recur();
</script>
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

riot.observable add `busy` flag to the function that passed to `trigger` until complete calling.
It might be to prevent infinite loop caused by an event firing another event.

So you cannot use riot observable in recursive function.